# Extract Hashtags and Mentions into separate fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I am doing a DIY Tweet Sentiment analyser, I have an index of tweets like these

```
"_source" : {
      "id" : 26930655,
      "status" : 1,
      "title" : "Here’s 5 underrated #BTC and realistic crypto accounts that everyone should follow:  @Quinnvestments , @JacobOracle , @jevauniedaye , @ginsbergonomics , @InspoCrypto",
      "hashtags" : null,
      "created_at" : 1622390229,
      "category" : null,
      "language" : 50
    },
    {
          "id" : 22521897,
          "status" : 1,
          "title" : "#bulls gonna overtake the #bears soon #ATH coming #ALTSEASON #BSCGem #eth #btc #memecoin #100xgems #satyasanatan """,
          "hashtags" : null,
          "created_at" : 1620045296,
          "category" : null,
          "language" : 50
    }
```

There Mappings are settings are like

```
"sentiment-en" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "category" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        
        "hashtags" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "language" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "status" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "raw_text" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "stop" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "index_options" : "docs",
              "analyzer" : "stop_words_filter"
            },
            "syn" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "index_options" : "docs",
              "analyzer" : "synonyms_filter"
            }
          },
          "index_options" : "docs",
          "analyzer" : "all_ok_filter"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




"settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "10",
        "provided_name" : "sentiment-en",
        "creation_date" : "1627975717560",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "stop_words" : {
              "type" : "stop",
              "stopwords" : [ ]
            },
            "synonyms" : {
              "type" : "synonym",
              "synonyms" : [ ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "stop_words_filter" : {
              "filter" : [ "stop_words" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            },
            "synonyms_filter" : {
              "filter" : [ "synonyms" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            },
            "all_ok_filter" : {
              "filter" : [ "stop_words", "synonyms" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "Q5yDYEXHSM-5kvyLGgsYYg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7090199"
        }
      }
```

Now the problem is i want to extract all the Hashtags and mentions in a seprate field.

What i want as O/P

```
          "id" : 26930655,
          "status" : 1,
          "title" : "Here’s 5 underrated #BTC and realistic crypto accounts that everyone should follow:  @Quinnvestments , @JacobOracle , @jevauniedaye , @ginsbergonomics , @InspoCrypto",
          "hashtags" : BTC,
          "created_at" : 1622390229,
          "category" : null,
          "language" : 50
        },
        {
              "id" : 22521897,
              "status" : 1,
              "title" : "#bulls gonna overtake the #bears soon #ATH coming #ALTSEASON #BSCGem #eth #btc #memecoin #100xgems #satyasanatan """,
              "hashtags" : bulls,bears,ATH, ALTSEASON, BSCGem, eth , btc, memecoin, 100xGem, satyasanatan
              "created_at" : 1620045296,
              "category" : null,
              "language" : 50
        }
```

What i have tried so far

1. Create a pattern based tokenizer to just read Hashtags and mentions and no other token for field hashtag and mentions did not had much success there.
2. Tried to write an n-gram tokenizer without any analysers did not achive much success there as well.

Any help would be appreciated, I am open to reindex my data. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: are you indexing data using logstash ?

Comment: @SagarPatel I was about to ask ! :D How do you ingest the data ? It might be easier to do it before pushing the data to elastic.

Comment: I am open to suggestions howsoever i am not using logstash,  And i either wanted to reindex the data in seprate index with Hashtags as a field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Logstash Twitter input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-twitter.html) for indexing data and configured below ruby script in filter plugin as mentioned in [blog](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/isolating-hashtags-in-twitter-feed/125532).

```
if [message] {
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('hashtags', event.get('message').scan(/\#[a-z]*/i))"
  }
}
```

You can use Logtstash Elasticsearch Input plugin for source index and configured about ruby code in Filter plugin and Logtstash elasticsearch output plugin with destination index.

```
input {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "current_twitter"
        query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
        size => 500
        scroll => "5m"
      }
    }
filter{
    if [message] {
      ruby {
        code => "event.set('hashtags', event.get('message').scan(/\#[a-z]*/i))"
      }
    }
}   
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "new_twitter"
    }
}
```

Another option is to use [reingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-with-an-ingest-pipeline) with ingest pipeline but ingest pipeline not support ruby code. So you need to convert above ruby code to the painless script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sagar ! However i would like to incline more towards reingest API. IS there any more cleaner approach possible for the same  using any form of tokenizers .I have found this tokenizer with solr ( https://github.com/wetneb/lucene-twitter/blob/master/src/test/java/org/opentapioca/analysis/twitter/TestTwitterTokenizer.java )

Comment: Can you also share an example painless script

Comment: @PrakharNigam Solr tokenizer link which you have shared it is custom tokenizer developed. so same is not available in Elasticsearch. You can also developed your custom tokenizer in Elasticsearch as well.